# Upload a folder with empty subfolders

Tags: javascript, file, directory, upload

I want to be able to select a folder and upload all its content (files and sub-folders), using

```
<input type="file" multiple directory id="uploader" />
```

The only way i found so far is:

- get the files selected from the 'change' event
- loop through the files
- for each file, get its containing folders from the webkitRelativePath property
- manage the actual backend call to create the right file structure

  ```
   const uploader = document.querySelector('#uploader');
   uploader.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
     const files = e.target.files;

     /// loop through the files
     for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
       // getting the folders list from files[i].webkitRelativePath
     }
   });
  ```

It's all good except when there's an empty sub-folder inside the selected folder. I would have no clue about its existence because what I'm looking at is the list of files coming from the input and not the list of "generic elements".

*Side note*:
the "empty subfolder issue" is not an issue if we use the **drop** action instead of the input[type=file].
The drop event comes with dataTransfer.items. These items can be converted into FileEntry objects. This would allow me to use the FileSystemDirectoryReader APIs and get all the type of entries (files and directories).

At first I thought getting empty subfolders from the input[type=file] was technically impossible, but then I discovered Google Drive and Microsoft One Drive webpages are actually uploading empty subfolders through their upload buttons! So there must be a way, I just couldn't find any more clues.